# Using Django Admin Page to Add Users with other AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

I'm using [django_auth_ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/) to authenticate users for a Django project against a large corporate ActiveDirectory system that's not organized in a useful way (and I don't have the ability to change it). As such, I have to add users individually so that I don't end up with any user who can authenticate against LDAP being able to sign into the system. It's possible to add LDAP users on the command line using

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

user = LDAPBackend().populate_user('alice')
```

but I can't use the admin page to do the same thing (adding user forces me to enter a password rather than just having the account inherit the LDAP credentials that already exist.)

It would appear that there isn't an easy/clever way to accomplish this without having to write a django admin page (though if I'm wrong on this, **please** correct me). How do I add a simple admin page that just creates a user without setting the password or anything else?

I understand that the basic mechanics basically involve doing something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

UserAdmin.add_form_template = ('addLDAPuser.html')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

but I'm still fuzzy on making a template and processing logic so that I don't just end up with a bunch of user accounts that will successfully authenticate against `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` with empty passwords. (Obviously, I could just remove `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` from the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in settings.py, but that also removes my ability to have a local admin account separate from LDAP.)

Comment: related to tagging of questions, [see this feedback I received about performing curatorial actions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197592/194328).  You'll find it interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could try is extending the standard user model and overriding its save() method. [Make sure you read up on the consequences of overriding the save method here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods). Such a model could look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class LDAPUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(username=self.username)
                self.user.save()
                '''
                Do custom saving here:
                from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

                user = LDAPBackend().populate_user('alice')
                '''
                super(LDAPUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.username
```

By not providing the user with a password, they cannot log in using the password field. Hopefully this means your LDAP backend will be the only way of authenticating for the LDAP users..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a clean way to do it without writing your custom admin page.

However, I wouldn't be so scared of it. Just create a new ModelAdmin for the auth.User model with your custom Form which will not require the password.